# Node js ternary operator why comparsion goes wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, boolean, ternary-operator

i have problem with ternary operator comparsion in node js script.
I have

```
function zip(fileName) {...}
process.env.TESTING = false;
zip(`${file}_${process.env.TESTING ? 'dev' : 'prod'}.zip`)
```

But fileName always file_dev.zip regardless of process.env.TESTING value

```
console.log(process.env.TESTING); // false
console.log(process.env.TESTING ? 'dev' : 'prod'); // always 'dev'
```

Why value is `boolean false` but comparsion result always `true`?

But browser console works as expected

Comment: Is it `false`, or `'false'`…?!

Comment: `process.env` will always contain strings. Instead of `false` you have `"false"` (= a string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  process.env.VARIABLE
```

Always stores value as string so `false` will be `'false'` and not boolean `false`.

```
process.env.VARIABLE === 'false'? 'prod':'dev'
```

Comment: `!!'false'` is also `true`…

Comment: then i guess you should check by using == 'false'

Answer (score 2):

If this value comes from the environment, won't its value be the **string** `'false'`? Can you confirm with `console.log(typeof process.env.TESTING)` that it's a boolean?

If it turns out to be a string, you should rewrite the comparison as `process.env.TESTING == 'false' ? 'prod' : 'dev'`